# Kotlin RxJava: Type mismatch, Observer required but ??? found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm implementing RxJava in my `Kotlin` project. Applying the automatic translation from Java to Kotlin to the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lobby_activity);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LobbyViewModel.class);

    viewModel.response().observe(this, response -> processResponse(response));
}
```

I have the error shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Show code and error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: This doesn't look like RxJava, but Android's `LiveData` observable data.

Comment: What is `LobbyViewModel`?

Comment: Sorry, guys. I'm trying this example https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c in Kotlin. And trying to converting Java to Kotlin, I have the error shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly declaring the type of the lambda:

```
viewModel!!.response().observe(this, Observer<Response> { response -> processResponse(response) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is it cannot resolve the type of `response` in the lambda. Try the following:

```
viewModel!!.response().observe(this, {response: Response -> ... })
```